# Why can't I mask this pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have no idea why the following code isn't working. I am trying to mask pandas arrays just like my advisor showed me but keep getting an error no matter what I do. Am i mixing up pandas dataframes with numpy arrays somehow? I looked up how to do this in another thread and I seem to be doing the same thing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

data_dir = "./data/"

incomes_file = "incomes.csv"

incomes = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_dir,incomes_file))

print incomes.County_Name
print incomes.County_Name[str(incomes.County_Name).isupper() != True]
```

I get this output:

```
0             ALABAMA
1      Autauga County
2      Baldwin County
3      Barbour County
4         Bibb County
5       Blount County
6      Bullock County
7       Butler County
8      Calhoun County
9     Chambers County
10    Cherokee County
11     Chilton County
12     Choctaw County
13      Clarke County
14        Clay County
...
3178    Hot Springs County
3179        Johnson County
3180        Laramie County
3181        Lincoln County
3182        Natrona County
3183       Niobrara County
3184           Park County
3185         Platte County
3186       Sheridan County
3187       Sublette County
3188     Sweetwater County
3189          Teton County
3190          Uinta County
3191       Washakie County
3192         Weston County
Name: County_Name, Length: 3193, dtype: object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Avi/Desktop/Average Income By County/data_analysis.py", line 13, in <module>
    print incomes.County_Name[str(incomes.County_Name).isupper()]
  File "/Users/Avi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 479, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Users/Avi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1171, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
  File "index.pyx", line 97, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2987)
  File "index.pyx", line 105, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2802)
  File "index.pyx", line 146, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3495)
  File "index.pyx", line 357, in pandas.index.Int64Engine._check_type (pandas/index.c:6813)
KeyError: False
[Finished in 1.4s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/Avi/Desktop/Average Income By County/data_analysis.py"]
[dir: /Users/Avi/Desktop/Average Income By County]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Comment: What result do you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
incomes[ incomes.Country_Name.apply(lambda x: x.isupper()) != True ]
```

You can't use `str()` on all DataFrame - (next time use `incomes.Country_Name.str`)
but there is no `incomes.Country_Name.str.isupper()` to make simpler solution.